# how to create refs for content that gets created later

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have a component that fetches data from an api upon user input. This data then gets rendered onto the screen as `<li/>` tags. I want those `<li/>` tags to have a `ref`.

I tried creating an object of refs that I create after the data is fetched:

```
 this.singleRefs = data.reduce((acc, value) => {
      acc[value.id] = React.createRef();
      return acc;
    }, {});
```

and then later assign these refs to the `<li/>` tag: `<li ref={this.singleRefs[element.id]}>`

but when I print them out I always have `{current:null}` [Here is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-rgb-gqx0mc?file=/src/App.js:786-836)

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dynamic ref data, I'd propose that you should use [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    this.singleRefs = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = [
      { value: "val1", id: 1 },
      { value: "val2", id: 2 },
      { value: "val3", id: 3 }
    ];
    this.myFunc(data);
    //you don't need this anymore
    // this.singleRefs = data.reduce((acc, value) => {
    //   acc[value.id] = React.createRef();
    //   return acc;
    // }, {});
  }

  myFunc = async (data) => {
    await sleep(3000);
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  renderContent() {
    return this.state.data.map(
      function (element, index) {
        return (
          <li key={index} ref={(node) => (this.singleRefs[element.id] = node)}>
            {element.value}
          </li>
        );
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.singleRefs);
    return <ul>{this.renderContent()}</ul>;
  }
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-leaf-km4rnh?file=/src/App.js)